# Assigning strings to ranges of numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a really simple problem. I have the following code:

```
  def age_color

    age = Time.now() - created_at

    age_color = 'green' if age < 2.days
    age_color = 'yellow' if age >= 2.days && age <= 5.days
    age_color = 'red' if age > 5.days

  end
```

which is not working properly anyway. I think it's ugly and reminds me of my PHP days. How can I write this more elegantly? It must never be nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construction doesn't work because you put it in wrong order. Try this

```
def age_color
  if    created_at < 5.days.ago then 'red'
  elsif created_at > 2.days.ago then 'green'
  else                               'yellow'  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [case](http://ruby.activeventure.com/usersguide/rg/control.html):

```
age_in_days = (Time.now() - created_at).days

age_color = case age_in_days
  when 0..1: 'green'
  when 2..5: 'yellow'
  else       'red'
end
```

The days method: http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Numeric/Time.html#M000322

Comment: There might be a more elegant way to calculate `age_in_days`.